# Problems for show branch in terminal

Tags: linux, git, shell, terminal

I have a problem with a shell script, it's in ~/.bashrc:

```
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
```

`PS1="\[${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\033[1;34m\u\033[1;34m@\h\033[0;32m:\w\033[1;35m $(parse_git_branch) $ \033[0m\]"`

I need it to show the current branch, and it's doing fine, but when I need to change directory to take a source ~ /. Bashrc to return to work.

Another problem is when I delete something wrong typed it erases all information on the line including vinicius@pontocom:~ (master) $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git already comes with shell scripts for showing the current branch, you can use them by adding

```
source '/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt.sh'
```

to your bash config file on OS X. If you're using Debian, you should be able to `source` the same file, but its installation path might be different.

You can also enable Git bash completions by sourcing this file as well:

```
source '/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you have a command substitution within double quotes, so it will only execute once, when you define PS1.

Try delaying the execution:

```
PS1="... \$(parse_git_branch) $ \033[0m\]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this piece of code in my .bashrc

```
parse_git_branch() {
        git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ [\1\]/'
}
PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\[\033[1;36m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[0m\] $ "
```

And the result is:

[image]